# Eliminar registro con funcion javascript

Tags: javascript

Buenas, lo que sucede es que tengo una tabla, donde tengo este link para eliminar un registro mediante php.

```
<a href="sqlEliminarAlumno.php?txtid='.$rut_alumno.'" onclick="confirmDel()">Eliminar</a>
```

y estoy tratando de eliminar el registro llamando a esta función,

```
    function confirmDel()
    {
      var agree=confirm("¿Realmente desea eliminarlo? ");
      if (agree) return true ;
      return false;
    }
```

pero me muestra el confirm en pantalla, presiono cancelar e igual se elimina el registro. ¿Cual es el problema? gracias de antemano :)

Comment: No habias hecho la misma pregunta hace unos dias ya?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo único que te falta es retornar el valor de la función al momento de ejecutarla: `onclick="return confirmDel()"` para poder anular el funcionamiento por defecto de la etiqueta `<a>`

```js
function confirmDel(){
  var agree=confirm("¿Realmente desea eliminarlo? ");
  if (agree) return true ;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="sqlEliminarAlumno.php?txtid='.$rut_alumno.'" onclick="return confirmDel()">Eliminar</a>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, eso era, pero, ¿me puedes explicar un poco la función del return en la etiqueta <a>?, muchas gracias :)

Comment: @alexigallegos claro, el return lo que hace es devolver un valor de la función, por lo cual al hacer onclick="confirmDel()" simplemente estarías recibiendo false o true (que es el valor que esta devolviendo return) con lo cual no estarías anulando el comportamiento por defecto de la etiqueta <a>, es por esa razón que debes hacer un return de la función como tal onclick="return confirmDel()" espero haber sido claro si no es así con gusto trato de explicarte de otra forma para hacerme entender mejor.